# Can I use the same REPO to two different Team Project on VSTS 2015

Tags: .net, git, tfs

I'm using Visual Team Foundation Server 2015 (on premisses).

I got two team that work in the same system : The Product Team and the Maintenance Team.

One is focus to Add Features, and the other to keep everything running and clean the bugs.

I thinking about create a Team Project for each team, but they can share the same REPO?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create separate projects for each but you can also create one project and then create two separate teams within that Project.  You can then easily manage a separate list of users and their permission for source code, work items, area paths, and iterations.

This is a good way to be able to see how the team overall is doing but also allow each "sub-team" to operate on their own and have their own backlogs.